# proxying outgoing traffic from local network

Tags: linux, apache, proxy

i have the following case: i've had an app hosted on some cloud hoster's server and it's own domain, now i've migrated from cloud to selfhosted and what i want to do is to redirect all users in my local network from the old domain to the new one i.e. when a user tipes previous url into  it's browser it opens new urk. The main problem is that i can't influence on the old domain, but can configure my local proxy server apache.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. The simplest way is to edit the hosts file on your local network computers (on windows you can find it in c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts (or /etc/hosts on Linux) and add the entry for your olddomain internalserverip like "IP_ADDRESS DOMAIN_NAME www.DOMAIN_NAME".
2. You will need to create a bind server on your local network to answers the local queries and configure the zone for your old domain like you would when the domain was hosted on cloud, you just need to put your internal server IP in the A entries.

In both situations if your web server is configured with only the new vhost entry , you will need to configure it with the old vhost (if there is no vhost configure you will not need to do anything)

Comment: did you try it on a real case?